# mssql 2008 r2 - How to remove and add dependencies to a table using query or stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to remove and add dependencies to a table using query or stored procedures?

Basically I have a table called A and it has a stored procedure dependency called B.

I want to create a new table called C and add the stored procedure dependency to C and Delete A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this without modifying the stored procedure? Technically you could do this using a [`SYNONYM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) (`DROP TABLE dbo.A; CREATE SYNONYM dbo.A FOR dbo.C;`) - assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 or higher (please specify your version!) - but this can become a nightmare of spaghetti and cascading references.

Comment: My problem is that for some reason my archive table is being referenced but not my new table (the depency is still in the archive table).

Comment: What do you mean by "being referenced"? Does the code say SELECT FROM A but the procedure is returning data from C? Or vice versa? Maybe you should be more specific so that the simplicity of A,B,C doesn't mislead anyone.

Comment: If SQL Server 2000, you can use a view to provide indirection, but it leads to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies like you are talking about aren't created independently (pun intended).  They are the result of the queries within the stored procedure.

To have the effect you are after you need to create your new table, and redirect the stored procedure to `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` from `C` instead of `A`.